# How to rewrite subfolder to another using apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite `www.example.com/blog-ie` to `www.example.com/blog`, the problem is that since it's a blog some url look like `www.example.com/blog-ie/2015/05/some-article` so I'm not sure how to keep the rest of the URL intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `.htaccess` or `VirtualHost`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule blog-ie(.*) /blog$1 [R,L]
```

First, the [RewriteEngine](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/) is activated. The rewrite rule basically tells the httpd to do the following

> When an URL beginning with "blog-ie" is called, take everything following that URL (`(.*)`) and append it (`$1`) to "/blog". Send a redirect to the client (`R`) and let this rule be the last one evaluated (`L`) if it matches.

With the bracket in the first part of the rule (the match part), you tell the RewriteEngine to remember everything within the brackets. This is called a match group. In the second part of the rule, the rewrite part, the first match group can be referenced with `$1`. If you had more match groups, you could reference them with `$2` and so on. This way of defining match groups and using them later is called backreferencing.

Comment: It would be nice if you explained this a bit.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg It was a poor question, OP made no effort to show what he did so he can figure out how this works on his own. He made no effort with the question so I made no effort with the answer

Comment: While this may be a valid quid pro quo for the OP, this doesn't apply to the next person with the same problem, does it? ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg if you want to explain it, go ahead. Or downvote it if you think its not a useful answer. I'm not going to waste my time writing an explanation to such a poor question. It still provides an answer to the problem.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg haha brilliant. *You* deserve an upvote for this. If only there was a way to allocate rep to another user...

Comment: Let me put it in [Pastafarian](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) terms: I'd really rather you didn't make me do it. ;)